# I've just written this class for an n-dimensional array object. Is there any way I can improve it?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

How would I write the toString method? And how could I change the way users can fill numbers?

Here's the code:

```
public class NArray
{
  private int[] intArray;
  private NArray[] array;

  public NArray(int n, int size, int fillNum)
  {
    if(n==1)
    {
      intArray = new int[size];

      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
        intArray[i]=fillNum;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      array=new NArray[size];

      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
        array[i] = new NArray(n-1,size, fillNum);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using polymorphism.

Comment: For what do you need that n-dim array? low memory consuption because huge number of totals elemenst? performant? only int values, or general objects?

Answer (score 0):

For the fill method, you could use `Arrays.fill` (see the [java API javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5b%5d,%20int%29)).

What do you want the toString() method to do?  Can't really answer that part without a spec.

Answer (score 0):

To use toString. An Example is shown Below. Please refer and implement..:) Happy Coding

```
public class Test{ 

   public static void main(String args[]){
      Integer x = 5;

      System.out.println(x.toString());  
      System.out.println(Integer.toString(12)); 
   }
}
```

For a tricky use..:)

```
class Bank
{


String n;
String add;
 int an;
 int bal;
 int dep;


public Bank(String n,String add,int an,int bal)
{

    this.add=add;this.bal=bal;
    this.an=an;this.n=n;

}

public  String toString()
{
    return "Name of the customer.:" + this.n+",, "+"Address of the customer.:"
                            +this.add +",, "+"A/c no..:"
                            +this.an+",, " +"Balance in A/c..:"+this.bal;
}
}
 public class Demo2 
 {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    List<Bank> l=new LinkedList<Bank>();


    Bank b1=new Bank("naseem1","Darbhanga,bihar",123,1000);
    Bank b2=new Bank("naseem2","patna,bihar",124,1500);
    Bank b3=new Bank("naseem3","madhubani,bihar",125,1600);
    Bank b4=new Bank("naseem4","samastipur,bihar",126,1700);
    Bank b5=new Bank("naseem5","muzafferpur,bihar",127,1800);
    l.add(b1);
    l.add(b2);
    l.add(b3);
    l.add(b4);
    l.add(b5);
    Iterator<Bank> i=l.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
}

}
```